# Limit of hypergeometric distribution when sample size grows with population size

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider choosing $Mn/6$ balls from a population consisting of $M$ balls of each of $n$ colors (so $Mn$ balls in total). So the density function of the sample is given by a multivariate hypergeometric distribution: $$f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \frac{\binom{M}{x_1}\cdots\binom{M}{x_n}}{\binom{Mn}{Mn/6}}.$$ Can one say anything about the limiting behavior of the distribution as $M\to\infty$, where the number of colors $n$ is fixed? Since the sample size grows at the same rate as the population size, this wouldn't converge to a binomial/multinomial distribution as it would if the sample size were fixed. Any help is appreciated! (The $1/6$ in $Mn/6$ is arbitrary, I'm just curious in general about the case where the sample size is always a fixed fraction of the population size).

I guess it wouldn't surprise me if nothing really useful can be said, in which case I have a related question. Suppose you consider the same scenario, but instead of starting off with $M$ balls of each color, we only started off with, say, $5M/6$ balls of each color. So the modified density function would be: $$g(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \frac{\binom{5M/6}{x_1}\cdots\binom{5M/6}{x_n}}{\binom{5Mn/6}{Mn/6}}.$$ As $M\to\infty$, is there any meaningful relationship between $f$ and $g$ that can be made? It vaguely seems to me like as $M$ grows large the two densities should look more and more alike, but it's possible that that intuition is awry.

Comment: It might be notationally easier to change the $n$'s to $N$'s? It would be natural to index the $M$ and $N$ balls with $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $m^{th}$ ball of color $n$ let $X_{m}^{n}$ be the indicator random variable for whether it was drawn. Suppose we are drawing fraction $\mu \in (0,1)$ of the balls in the population (e.g. $\mu = 1/6$), then:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{m}^{n}] = \mu$$

$$Var(X_{m}^{n}) = \mu(1-\mu) \equiv \sigma^{2}$$

For any $(m,n) \neq (m',n')$:

$$\begin{align}
Cov(X^{n}_{m}, X^{n'}_{m'}) &= \mathbb{E}[X_{m}^{n}X_{m'}^{n'}]-\mu^{2} \\
&= -\mu (1-\mu)/(MN-1) \\
&= -\sigma^{2}/(MN-1)
\end{align}$$

Fixing $N$, for any $M$ denote:
$$\bar{X}^{n}_{M} = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^{M} X_{m}^{n}$$
Which has the following properties:
$$\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}^{n}_{M}] = \mu$$

$$\begin{align}
Var(\bar{X}^{n}_{M}) &= \frac{1}{M^{2}} \left[ M Var(X_{m}^{n}) + M(M-1)Cov(X_{m}^{n}) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{M} \left[ Var(X_{m}^{n}) + (M-1)Cov(X_{m}^{n}) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{M} \left[ \sigma^{2} - (M-1)\sigma^{2}/(MN-1) \right] \\
&= \frac{\sigma^{2}}{M}\left( \frac{M(N-1)}{MN-1} \right)
\end{align}$$

Define $Y^{n}_{M} = \sqrt{M}(\bar{X}^{n}_{M} - \mu)$, then by the central limit theorem $Y^{n}_{M}$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \sigma^{2}(N-1)/N)$.  (Note the central limit theorem still applies here though the random variables are slightly dependent. Cite Theorem 1 of "The Central Limit Theorem For Dependent Random Variables" by Wassily Hoeffding and Herbert Robbins.)

The covariance for $n \neq n'$ is:

$$Cov(\bar{X}^{n}_{M}, \bar{X}^{n'}_{M}) = Cov(X^{n}_{m}, X^{n'}_{m'}) = -\sigma^{2}/(MN-1)$$

$$\Rightarrow Cov(Y^{n}_{M}, Y^{n'}_{M}) = M\sigma^{2}/(MN-1) \rightarrow -\sigma^{2}/(N-1)$$

Thus, $(Y^{1}_{M}, \ldots , Y^{N}_{M})$ converges in distribution to a multivariate normal centered around $0$ with a covariance matrix that has $\sigma^{2}(N-1)/N$ on the diagonal and $-\sigma^{2}/(N-1)$ on the off-diagonal.  (Note, this covariance matrix has rank $N-1$.)

(To prove $(Y^{1}_{M}, \ldots , Y^{N}_{M})$ does indeed converge to a multivariate normal, we would have to show any linear combination of them converges to a normal, which follows via the same argument used to show $Y^{n}_{M}$ converges to a normal.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that in the present case a limiting distribution exists in the strict sense as $M\to\infty$. However, it seems to be the case that the hypergeometric distribution approaches a normal distribution in this limit, with diminishing height, increasing average and deviation. More explicitly, consider the case $n=2$, for which the hypergeometric distribution reads:

$$P(x)=\frac{\binom{m}{x}\binom{M-m}{N-x}}{\binom{M}{N}}$$

and to tackle the particular problem at hand set $m=\frac{M}{2}~,~N=fM~,~ f< 1/2$. Note that if the sampling fraction exceeds the critical value $1/2$ it becomes more complicated to obtain a simple estimate using the Stirling approximation for the factorial, so I will work with the previously mentioned restricted case. In this case it is clear that $x\in [0,fM]$. After plugging in the Stirling approximation $$x!\approx x^xe^{-x}\sqrt{2\pi x}$$

and simplifying we obtain a monstrous expression for $P(x)$ in the limit $M\to\infty$ which I will omit for now. The limit of this expression as one lets $M$ grow is, strictly speaking, zero. However, it turns out that $\ln P(x=fMt)$ is proportional to $M$. This points to the fact that as $M\to\infty$, since $\ln P<0$ only points near the maximum of $P$ will attain non-zero values. We see that the maximum is attained at $t=1/2$. With this, we conclude after simplification that

$$P(x)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi f(1-f)M}}\exp\left[-\frac{2}{f(1-f)M}(x-fM/2)^2\right]$$

This means that the distribution moves further along the x-axis as $M\to\infty$ but also shortens and broadens to keep the normalization constant. Numerical evidence supports this result as shown in the plot below.[image: P(x) vs. x]